# How can I define hierarchical levels in eCognition

Tags: spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, ecognition

I'd like to define classes with 2 levels. Firstly I'm gonna classify some broad classes such as forest, grassland in a level 1. Furthermore, I'd like to classify these classes into some sub-classes such as Evergreen forest, deciduous forest etc. Grassland will also be classified into 3 sub-classes as well. How can I define this hierarchical levels in eCognition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Classify the broad classes initially.
2. Create the sub class for example 'Deciduous forest' in class hierarchy windowand Select your broad class say 'Forest' in 'Parent class for display' field.[image]
3. Or drag and drop the sub class to the main. [image]
4. When creating rule set for classify the 'Deciduous forest', select 'Forest' in 'Class filter' field. It means, the image objects of 'Forest' class only will consider for the classification of 'Deciduous forest'.
   [image]

Sandhya

Comment: @Bandrush Barda, is the above method works for your classification?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well. Again I want to make sure something about choosing level 1, 2, 3 etc on 'Level' field on the last 'Edit process' window. Once I click on 'level' field, only 'New level' can be seen instead of 'level 1' How can I set this parameter as a level 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: The 'New Level' is default. You can define your own level by clicking and edit the level name on 'level' filed. You may opt several levels but if you want to work with the second level, first level should be deleted.